# Using Partition By to compare values based on date in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, partition-by

I have a table called *referrals*

```
CREATE TABLE [dataproduct].[referrals]
(
      [person_id] DOUBLE,
      [medical_service_cd] DOUBLE,
      [refer_from_organization_id] 
      [referral_org_name] STRING, 
      [refer_from_provider_id] DOUBLE, 
      [provider_from_name] STRING,  
      [refer_to_provider_id] DOUBLE,
      [provider_to_name] STRING,  
      [outbound_encntr_id DOUBLE,
      [order_id] DOUBLE,
      [referral_written_dt_tm] STRING,
      [requested_start_dt_tm] STRING,  
      [medical_service] STRING,  
      [referral_status] STRING, 
      [loc_code] STRING,  
      [service_type] STRING,
      [referral_reason] STRING,  
      [treatment_text] STRING

)
```

I want to find patients, by **person_id**, who were referred to Neurology FOLLOWED BY Medical Genetics (as listed under **medical_service**) using **referral_written_dt_tm**. I confirmed that some patients had both medical services, but want to find the ones who had them in the desired order. so I tried this:

```
  SELECT r.person_id, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT r.medical_service) as count,
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY referral_written_dt_tm ASC) AS row_num 
    FROM matt_dataproduct.referrals r
   WHERE r.medical_service IN ('Medical Genetics',
                               'Neurology'
                               )
GROUP BY r.person_id,
  HAVING count > 1;
```

I got no results. I just want a list of patients who meet the criteria (medical genetics followed by neurology). Is there some way I should revise my query? Something about it seems off.

Comment: How does this query enforce the order? It looks like you're just trying to get patients who have had both of these services.

Comment: I'm not sure how to enforce the order, can you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is probably something like the following:

```
SELECT r.person_id 
FROM matt_dataproduct.referrals rmg INNER JOIN matt_dataproduct.referrals rn
 ON rmg.person_id = rn.person_id
WHERE rmg.medical_service ='Medical Genetics'
 AND rn.medical_service = 'Neurology'
 AND rn.eferral_written_dt_tm < rmg.eferral_written_dt_tm
GROUP BY r.person_id
```

This simply joins the table to itself (once for Neurology and once for Medical Genetics) and finds rows where the same patient has Neurology before Medical Genetics. The `group by` is being used to get distinct values (could use `distinct` in the `select` part instead).

You said the type of `eferral_written_dt_tm` is a string (not an actual date). I'm assuming it's directly comparable without conversion (since you used it in your window function's `order by`), but if not you would replace `rn.eferral_written_dt_tm < rmg.eferral_written_dt_tm` with the appropriate functions or conversions so that it's comparable.

You could use the `row_number` window function as you tried (or maybe a variation with `lag`) by wrapping it in another query to compare values. But in this case I don't see any big advantage over the simple self-join.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know self-join was possible . it worked.